# How to choose between the two methods Action Filter and Override the routes for overriding the Core Controller Action Method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, action-filter

I want to change some code in an action of the **CategoryNavigation** action from the **CatalogController**. I don't want to alter the core code of NopCommerce so i need to try to overide the code with my own custom code and this i want to do with my plugin.

> What I basically want is the same function of the original code but
>   with some custom tweaks.

I am having this class:

```
public partial class NumberofVisittoProducts : BaseEntity
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int ProductVisitStatistics{ get; set; }
    }
```

So i want to increment **ProductVisitStatistics** Value when Particular **Product Detail page is open.**

> So far i have successfully managed to create this table with my
>   plugin.

I have tried to study alot regarding overriding a Controller from the below link:

[How to implement an Action Filter in NopCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723821/how-to-implement-an-action-filter-in-nopcommerce?rq=1)

[Very Close but not quite able to override core view nopcommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241961/very-close-but-not-quite-able-to-override-core-view-nopcommerce)

http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/24127/overriding-other-controllers-and-their-routes.aspx

So I am so much confused between the two.

Now say i use **Action filter** then I am not getting it how do i get that Particular **ProductId** then.

For 2nd Method that is **override the Route** i am not getting that how do i use it and perform my functionality like update **ProductVisitStatistics** in my table.

So If anybody can Please help me with this??

I am ready to send my plugin project if anybody wants to see what i have done.