# Nopcommerce Product Listing Controller

Tags: nopcommerce, custom-action-filter

I am trying to do some custom programming in NopCommerce 3.50.

I have created custom filter attribute that performs required check when any controller or action method is accessed. I want to place this action filter at the place where all products are getting listed but i am not able to find any action method or controller which fetches the list of products.

Can any one let me know which controller or action method should i look for in the solution ?

Basically nop commerce follows the url rewriting with friendly names of categories i want to place my filter on that controller. so if my url is www.xyz.com/toys then i want to know to which controller this url will hit in code in order to get products of toys category ?

Comment: for Product Listing Check into Product Controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nopcommerce will hit the CatalogController. And will then use the Category action method to get the products in the category Toys.
Also you should use a action filter if you are going to rewrite a action inside a nopcommerce folder.

See posts:
[[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723821/how-to-implement-an-action-filter-in-nopcommerce]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723821/how-to-implement-an-action-filter-in-nopcommerce])[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723821/how-to-implement-an-action-filter-in-nopcommerce])
and
http://www.pronopcommerce.com/overriding-intercepting-nopcommerce-controllers-and-actions

Comment: Thansk. I also figured this out by intercepting requests. :) Thanks for your response.